# Angular velocity of (non-trivial) rigid object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

I'm considering the rigid object $S$ (2D) with following point masses:

**mass**(kg) | **position**(m) | **speed**(m/s)
1                        (3 -7)               (19 3)
2                        (0 2)                (1 -3)
3                        (1 3)                (-1 -1)
4                        (2 4)                (-3 1)
2                       (-1 1)                (3 -5)

Straightforward, centre of mass of this object is given by $C_{m} = (1,2)$ and Average speed $V_{avg} = (1,-1)$.

I get stuck with angular velocity $\omega$. I know that $\omega$ should be constant, independently of mass point taking into consideration, but probably here comes my poor understanding of fundamental physics (it's side-project for me). I've found two formulas for calculating angular velocity:
$$\omega := \frac{|v|}{|r|}$$
where r is distance from $C_m$ to given point mass $p$ and v is speed at this point

and

$$ \omega := \frac{r \times v}{|r|^{2}} = \frac{r_x  v_y  - r_yv_x}{r_x^2 + r_y^2} $$

But both of given formulas are giving different results depending of the point mass.

Could I ask for any hint?

Comment: I have made a 2d representation of the points and their velocity using GeoGebra. Link [here](http://imgur.com/a/ABxKJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation assumes that the velocity is perpendicular to the line from point $p$ to the center of mass. The second equation is more general and is identical to the first when the v and r are assumed to be perpendicular (almost identical that is. Because of the absolute values is the first equation there is no difference between left handed and right handed rotations. In the second equation the angular momentum becomes negative when the rotation is inverted).

Note that in both cases the velocity and position are calculated with respect to the center of mass. So:

$\omega=\frac{\left|\mathbf{v}\right|}{\left|\mathbf{r}\right|}=\frac{\left|\mathbf{v}_p-\mathbf{v}_{cm}\right|}{\left|\mathbf{r}_p-\mathbf{r}_{cm}\right|}$,

where $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ are given with respect to the center of mass and $\mathbf{v}_p, \mathbf{v}_{cm},\mathbf{r}_p$ and $\mathbf{r}_{cm}$ are given with respect to the origin.

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond! It's very nice explanation of yours, but I'm just don't get what exactly $v_{cm}$ and $r_{cm}$  stands for. As far as I concern the center of mass is fixed point (in sense of not moving) so it doesn't have any velocity of its own. And what about $r_{cm}$ means? I understand r as distance (vector) from $C_m$ to given point p, thus I don't see a difference between $r$ and $r_{cm}$.

Comment: Thanks for details in edit and once again for help. Have a nice day!

Comment: @kst I updated the answer to clarify the reference points. Note that while the center of mass is a fixed point within the object, it is not a fixed point in space. As the object moves through space, the center of mass moves along with it. Note that your table gives the absolute positions $\mathbf{r}_p$ and the absolute velocities $\mathbf{v}_p$

Comment: But how to get $v_{cm}$?

Comment: @kst hint: You already calculated $\mathbf{v}_{cm}$ in your question.